# Two prefix commands for tmux?

Tags: tmux

We have a tmux session that several people need to connect to. Some people like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> prefix shortcut and some people prefer the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> shortcut. Is there anything I can put in the `.tmux.conf` file to allow **both** shortcuts to work?

It seems that the standard

```
set -g prefix C-a
```

command will unset the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> shortcut.

I have also tried this:

```
set -g prefix C-a
set -g prefix C-b
```

but the second line then unsets the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For releases prior to 2012: Issue the command only once, with all the desired prefix keys separated by commas:

```
set-option -g prefix C-a,C-b
```

For versions >= 1.6 (Released the day before your question, 23/01/2012) see the other answer.

Answer (score 41):

[angus’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29892/80216) is correct for **tmux 1.5** and earlier.

However, this has [changed](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1.6/CHANGES#L42) in **tmux 1.6**. 
Now, there are two options, `prefix`, and `prefix2`,
each of which can only be set to a single value, like this:

```
set-option -g prefix C-a
set-option -g prefix2 C-b
```

Comment: If you need to send the secondary prefix key to a window, you can use the `-2` option of `send-prefix` (for the example given in the answer, `send-prefix -2` would send `C-b` to the window).